# click event not firing in backbone for iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

i have this project bundled with backbone,require.js underscore,jquerymobile into cordova or phonegap to deploy in iOS. but the click event is not working. i have this.

```
events:{
    "click #log" : "Login"
    },

<a data-role="button" id="log">Log In</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your entire html code for your view and also show your entire code for your Backbone view

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure your anchor is inside your view element?